# mongoDB GeoJSON, Query near two point, or line

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I have a collection like this :

```
origin: {
    location : {
        type: String,
        coordinates: [lgnt,lat]
    }
},
destination: {
    location : {
        type: String,
        coordinates: [lgnt,lat]
    }
}
```

With an index : '2dsphere' on location.origin and location.destination.

Then I got an other 'from' point and 'to' point, and I am trying to get all documents in the DB that :

- origin is around 'from' point
- destination is arond 'to' point.

For one OR the other,it is ok :

```
db.find({
   'origin.location': {
       $nearSphere: {
           $geometry: {
               type: "Point",
               coordinates: [from.lng, from.lat]
           },
           $maxDistance: 10
       }
   }
})
```

However in the docs, it is written, that I cannot use two $near query. I try some stuff like :

```
db.find({
  'origin.location': {
    $nearSphere: {
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [from.lng, from.lat]
      },
      $maxDistance: 10
    }
  },
  'destination.location': {
    $nearSphere: {
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [to.lng, to.lat]
      },
      $maxDistance: 10
    }
  }
});
```

Is not working because of the use of two $near/$nearSphere.
So I tried with

```
$and : [
    $near: ...,
    $near: ...
]
```

It is not working either.
I tried with an aggregate but you cannot use `$near` in `$match`.
What would you do ?

- Maybe i am missing something here ?
- can I use `LineString` and try to query a 'similar' `LineString`, but how to do that ?
- The current solution is to do 2 queries, one for the origin, one for the destination, and then in the client to intersect the two tabs so I'll have my result, but it's 2 queries.

P.S : I also tried :

```
var origines = db.find({
  'origin.location': {
    $nearSphere: {
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [from.lng, from.lat]
      },
      $maxDistance: 10
    }
  }
}, {
  _id: 1
})
origines = origines.map(function(elem) {
  return elem._id;
});
db.find({
  $and: [{
    _id: {
      $in: origines
    }
  }, {
    'destination.location': {
      $nearSphere: {
        $geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [to.lng, to.lat]
        },
        $maxDistance: 10
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

But nope

Comment: hey @Dakkon_jareth did you find any solution for your problem?

Comment: @demsey No it seems it is not possible with mongo at this time. So I used two queries. But turns out I got perf problems afterwards. So I just had to use other solutions.

Comment: thanks @Dakkon_jareth

Answer (score 0):

Since mongoDB 4.2 you can calculate the distance to destination and then use match.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [ from.lng, from.lat ]
            },
            distanceField: "distanceToOrigin",
            maxDistance: 10,
            spherical: true
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "distanceToDestination" : {
                $multiply: [
                    6371000,
                    { $acos: { $add: [
                        { $multiply: [
                            { $sin: { $degreesToRadians: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$destination.location.coordinates", 1]} } },
                            { $sin: { $degreesToRadians: to.lat } }
                        ]},
                        { $multiply: [
                            { $cos: { $degreesToRadians: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$destination.location.coordinates", 1]} } },
                            { $cos: { $degreesToRadians: to.lat } },
                            { $cos: { $degreesToRadians: { "$subtract": [ { "$arrayElemAt": ["$destination.location.coordinates", 0] }, to.lng ] } } }
                        ]}
                    ] } }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { "distanceToDestination": {$lt: 10} }
    }
])
```

Comment: I like the idea, but I get erroneous distance with the formula (way over 700000m for a distance that should be 0, destination=to). Someone managed to make it work?